# How can i enable a rich text box functionality on a custom webpart (New Form SP2010)

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-designer

In SP 2007  when i add a custom new form webpart with a multiple line of text field i use to get the richtextbox feature
But in SP 2010  custom new form webpart with multiple line of text field doesnt give you the richtext functionality
Any ideas how i can get this to work.

*** When i add a dataview webpart the fileds with  multiple line of text doesn't have the 
richtext functionality ***

Thanks

Comment: This solution didnt work for me in designer.Anyone

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox ID="abc" runat="server" RichText="true" TextMode="MultiLine" RichTextMode="FullHtml" Columns="200" Rows="10" />
```

Comment: How would i use this in SPD 2010?